# Can not select software source in Software Center Kubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: kubuntu, plasma

I am using Kubuntu 16.04.2 with KDE Plasma 5.8.5. In Software Center (Discover) I cannot select software source. When I click more from setting nothing is showing.

Comment: can you launch `software-properties-gtk` in terminal (Konsole)?

Comment: @ElderGeek In Kubuntu it's called `software-properties-kde` (though if that one's not working, I suppose they could install the GTK version) :)

Comment: @NickWeinberg That's good to know, what I'm looking for from the OP here is any error messages from the terminal that might make the issue clearer.

Comment: Thanks @NickWeinberg,  `software-properties-kde` is working

Answer (score 0):

I believe [you've hit this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/muon/+bug/1612392) or similar to something like that. The bug status says, there is a fix for Zesty, but Xenial is still under affected list.

I have experienced same and found a possible workaround. Just downgrade the `plasma-discover` package for a while.

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-discover/xenial-updates
```

should do the job.